# How to use the same custom page template to iframe multiple urls with entry of new url entered from backend

Tags: customization, page-template

I am using this custom page template to iframe mulptiple urls. Currently I have been making a new custom page for each new url. I want to be able to use the same generic custom page template, and be able to enter the new url from the dashboard. What is the easiest way to do this without creating a new custom page for each new URL that i want enter.? Any advice would be greatly appreciate.

Title
    
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }
        iframe{ 
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. Two easy ones that come to mind are post meta (probably using a plugin to make it easier) and custom shortcodes.

### Post meta

WordPress allows you to associate different pieces of "meta" data to each post. So for this approach, you create a new meta field ("iframe_url" ?). Then on each page you just enter the meta *value* for that meta *key*. On your page template, you reference that meta value, which will be different for each page.

You can get and set post meta without a plugin, but many developers use a plugin for this because of the added flexibility (i.e. creating complex hierarchies of data) and ease. The one I am most familiar with is Advanced Custom Fields, which is mostly functional even in the free version. There is a GUI to create fields and assign them to pages, and in your code referencing the value is as simple as `get_field( 'iframe_url' )`

### Custom shortcode

For dynamic data that lives in the content area and is also relatively simple, you can create a custom shortcode to store the url. In your post content, it might look something like:

```
[customframe url="http://myiframecontent.com"][/customframe]
```

Then in your functions.php or elsewhere, you tell WordPress what to do with that shortcode when it finds it. For instance:

```
function wpse330544_iframe_shortcode( $atts ) {
    
    $args = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'url'   => ''   //default value, just to show the technique
        ), 
        $atts
    );

    $url = esc_attr( $args['url'] );
     
    return "<iframe src='$url' />";
}
add_shortcode('customframe', 'wpse330544_iframe_shortcode');
```

It's really as simple as defining a function to handle the dynamic content. In that function we first extract the parameters (you have only one, "url"), then we prepare it for insert into HTML attributes safely (esc_attr), then we return the populated, dynamic HTML, which WordPress puts in place of your shortcode.